# Can't see log entries in Live Metrics of Application Insights

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-application-insights, serilog

I'm using Serilog in my ASP.Net web api services to log to Application Insights.
If I query the traces on the "Logs" page of the Application Insights instance in the Azure portal so the log entries are being sent / received.

However, I want to view the logs in the Live Metrics section so that I can see them as they happen rather than having a 5-10 minute latency, which makes debugging slow and laborious.

The documentation seems to indicate that this should work but I can't find anything that I've not done, except for the authentication of the Live Metrics connection.

I can see the requests as they happen, so the connection to my services is working, it's only the log entries in the traces that aren't working.
I checked the filters on the Live Metrics panel and turned off all filters but still no log entries show.

Is it possible to see the full logs here and if so how do I enable it?

I'm really not sure what code / config would be useful here but I will add it if anyone wants to see some of it.

I'm using .Net 7 with the NuGet packages:

- Serilog v2.12.0
- Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights v4.0.0
- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Kubernetes v6.1.0
- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Profile.AspNetCore v2.5.1

The services are running in Azure Kubernetes Services

Comment: Have you enabled Live Metrics option in your AKS Cluster.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpx23.png)

Comment: @Harshitha As far as I can see, there's no way to view log entries on the Insights page of the Kubernetes service. That toggle appears to be for turning on / off live data on that page only and only applies to the current session.
I'm trying to get the logs working with live metrics working on the Application insights page in the Azure Portal.

Comment: AFAIK,live metrics will be enabled if the app is deployed in azure app service and app insights is enabled in it.